# Overloading operators outside of class definition

Tags: c++

I want to overload `operator-` to give the distance between two iterators passed as arguments.

My class is a list and I have the iterator class nested inside my list.

I cannot seem to get the correct form of the function. I have not had the chance to test out the body. My main problem with the function is how I am defining it.

```
size_t operator-(template <class T> typename mylist<T>::iterator a, template <class T> typename mylist<T>::iterator b) {
    size_t i = 0;
    while(a.node != b.node) {
        ++a;
        ++i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct definition should be like this:

```
template <class T>
size_t operator-(const mylist<T>::iterator& a, const mylist<T>::iterator& b) {
   ... put logic here... 
}
```

A `operator-` is not supposed to modify its arguments while yours does, which is generally not very good. You can fix that by passing copies of the arguments:

```
template <class T>
size_t operator-(mylist<T>::iterator a, mylist<T>::iterator b) {
   ... put logic here... 
}
```

Comment: If I want to use this operator subsequently for a `list` function, what must I add? Because as it is, I still get an invalid operand error.

Comment: @Dochevsky what is a list **function**?

Comment: What I mean is a function in my list class. So I have `template <class T> class list { class iterator {/*...*/}; iterator insert(iterator, T); /*...*/ };` I am trying to use the `-` operand inside my `insert` function.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into how to properly [template a function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template).

```
template<class T>
void function(const T& t) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template <class T>
size_t operator-(typename mylist<T>::iterator a, typename mylist<T>::iterator b) 
{
    size_t i = 0;
    while(a.node != b.node) {
        ++a;
        ++i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

or

```
template <class Iterator>
size_t operator-(Iterator & a, const Iterator & b) 
{
    size_t i = 0;
    while(a.node != b.node) {
        ++a;
        ++i;
    }
    return i;
}
```

note the references and const on the iterator that doesn't change (you may not want to pass a by reference if you don't want it to change.)